# Mapping multiple touch screens persistently (Current it resets after session locked or when plugged to a different USB port)

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I have a touch screen laptop (Thinkpad X1 Yoga Gen 2, Ubuntu 20.04) connected to an external touch screen monitor. The touch screens' mapping don't work at plug-in so I followed [this guide](https://networks.guru/2018/11/23/using-dual-monitor-dual-touch-screens-on-ubuntu/) to map the input devices to the respective monitors. I've followed the guide and added a `~/.config/autostart/align_touchinput.desktop` file to allow the mapping to be executed everytime I log in.

Here's my setup:

```
xinput
...
↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger touch  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser    id=25   [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ WingCoolTouch WingCoolTouch               id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ WingCoolTouch WingCoolTouch               id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
....

xrandr
...
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+3072+160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
HDMI-1 connected 3072x1728+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 195mm
...
```

From the above, WingCoolTouch and HDMI-1 are from the external monitor. Thus I get my PC to run this script at startup:

```
xinput map-to-output 18 HDMI-1
xinput map-to-output 19 HDMI-1
xinput map-to-output 9 eDP-1
xinput map-to-output 10 eDP-1
xinput map-to-output 24 eDP-1
```

However, I'm facing two problems:

1. **Every time when I wake up my laptop from sleep/screen turning off, the mapping always resets. Is there a good solution to this issue?**
2. Because it's a laptop I often have to plug in the touch screen via a different USB port. This changes the `id` from `xinput`. From what I understand, `xinput map-to-input` allows mapping by device name. But my OS has detected multiple devices with the same name so it doesn't work (I get "Warning: There are multiple devices matching 'WingCoolTouch WingCoolTouch'" and an error). **Is there anyway to map everything named `WingCoolTouch` to `HDMI-1` so the mapping will work regardless of the USB port I use**?

Comment: This question and link to the guide helped me to configure dual touch screen on ASUS Zenbook Duo. Thanks. In case anybody else needs it: `xinput map-to-output $(xinput | grep ELAN9009:00 | grep -v 'Touchpad\|Stylus' | awk -F' ' '{print substr ($5, 4)}') DP-1`

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, wrote a script:

```
#! /bin/bash

one=$(xinput --list | grep -F 'WingCoolTouch' | grep -Po '(?<=id=)\d\d?' | head -n 1)
two=$(xinput --list | grep -F 'WingCoolTouch' | grep -Po '(?<=id=)\d\d?' | tail -n 1)

xinput map-to-output $one HDMI-1
xinput map-to-output $two HDMI-1
```

Comment: I assume the script permitted you to solve the issue... in that case, please mention that.

Comment: sure, it solves problem #2 of topic starter by "map everything named WingCoolTouch to HDMI-1 so the mapping will work regardless of the USB port I use" .